# Delegates - jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm adding some elements dynamycally using jquery (.append). Each element is given class = "bye".

this is the appending function:

```
$("#solicitadas").append('<div class= "bye">'+"save was clicked"+  '<img src="x.jpg">'+conteo+"</div>");
```

following is my function:

```
$(".bye").on('click',function(events){
  $(this).remove();
  return false;
});
```

However, when I do click one of the dynamically generated elements, they aren't removed. I have placed  some text (just to check if it was working on not dynamic content) and the function is being called corectly from there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your binding only to the events for the classes available at the time try:

```
$('body').on('click', '.bye ',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).remove();

});
```

Comment: Thnak you Johny, what's the difference between using  body VS document?

Comment: I'm not 100%, I believe you can bind to the document as well, both document and body should be there for the life time of you page request.  I'm just accustom to binding to the 'body' element because I've never had problems binding for dynamic elements with this.  Hopefully this answer helped you out, if it did please mark it as resolve or up vote thx!

Answer (score 1):

What your code do is bind the events only to available element.. there a slightly different syntax to bind event to dynamically generated elements.. you can try this...

```
$("#solicitadas").on('click', '.bye', function(events){
  $(this).remove();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, is there an advantage of using this solution instead of the ones proposed by Peter and Johny? Or is it just another way to get the same result? Regards.

Comment: the on function binds to the element selected so the event will be there for the life time of this object.

Comment: It binds the event to only those elements with class 'bye' which will be appended to the element having id 'solicitadas'. whereas if you use 'document' or 'body' then it binds event to all element having class 'bye'. It doesn't care whether the element is inside element 'solicitadas' or not..

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

```
$(document).on("click", ".bye", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).remove(); 
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#solicitadas").append('<div class="bye">SOME TEXT</div>');
      $(document).on("click", ".bye", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="solicitadas"></div>
```